# How to prevent client keylogging from server?

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, web-deployment, keylogger

As a web developer, Using HTTPS can prevent man-in-the-middle attack AFAIK. But is there ways to prevent keylogging clients sensitive information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a web developer, you only have a certain level of control of the client - essentially, whatever the browser allows you to do with client side scripts. So, nothing much can be done to completely prevent keyloggers in client devices (which are usually run at system-level and not confined to the browser).

One popular way of mitigation is using virtual keyboards, which the users can make use of via the mouse. Many bank sites use it extensively.

[image: Virtual Keyboard]

It can defeat naive keyloggers, but still they are vulnerable to [RATs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration_software), which often have access to the victim's screen too.